# Does Windows load a driver that is loaded using OsrLoader at the startup?

Tags: windows, drivers

I start learning Windows drivers development and I wrote my first driver. I use [OsrLoader](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157) for loading and unloading the drivers. So far everything is fine. However, As we know, if a driver crashes the whole system crashes. The worst thing can happen is that Windows loads that buggy driver at the system start-up.

My question is that does Windows load a driver that is loaded using OsrLoader at the startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OsrLoader only loads the driver for the current session. It does not cause it to be loaded next time you reboot.